# First non-repeated character C# LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I've tried some answers from Stackoverflow but they don't count register of the symbols. For example

> sTreSS => T (not 's'),
> stress => t

Here is what i tried

```
public static char FirstNonRepeatedCharacter(string s)
        {
            var output = s.GroupBy(item => item).First(x => x.Count() == 1).Key;
            return output;
        }
```

I need to edit the code with case-insensitive  and return the correct register

> sEVeraL -> s; - SomeBody - S

Comment: What is _register of the symbols_?

Comment: Upper case / lower case

Comment: What is a "non-counting register"? Do you mean "case-insensitive", perhaps?

Comment: yeah,you're rigt

Comment: Group by `char.ToLower(item)` or `char.ToUpper(item)` (perhaps with an additional CultureInfo parameter like CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, or some such). Then in the first found group with `x.Count() == 1`, don't get the key but the first (and only) element in the group (which should be the character in its original letter case)

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace thanks, done it. But how can i return another value in case all the letters repeat?

Comment: Use `FirstOrDefault`. Check its official documentation for how it behaves if there are no groups with the criteria `x => x.Count() == 1` to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what you need, but not fully in LINQ. In my opinion, you don't have to strictly rely on LINQ...

```
Console.WriteLine(FirstNonRepeatedCharacter("sTreSS"));
Console.WriteLine(FirstNonRepeatedCharacter("stress"));
Console.WriteLine(FirstNonRepeatedCharacter("sEVeraL"));
Console.WriteLine(FirstNonRepeatedCharacter("SomeBody"));
Console.WriteLine(FirstNonRepeatedCharacter("AaBbCc"));
Console.ReadKey();

static char? FirstNonRepeatedCharacter(string s)
{
    // Gather the count for each character (case insensitive, example: 's' and 'S' is in the same group).
    var counts = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    foreach (var ch in s.ToLower())
    {
        counts[ch] = counts.TryGetValue(ch, out var count)
            ? count + 1
            : 1;
    }

    // Return first character with count 1.
    return s.FirstOrDefault(ch => counts[char.ToLower(ch)] == 1);
}
```

Output is:

T

t

s

S

nothing (null)

Comment: This is almost what i need. Almost because i don't need to return null. I need to return an empty string. I've already edited this code and it has passed all the tests!

Answer (score 1):

You can group by characters as they are, but by processed character:

```
    .GroupBy(c => char.ToLower(c), c => c)
```

**Code:**

```
    // either first not repeating character or '\0'
    private static char FirstNonRepeatedCharacter(string s) => s
       ?.GroupBy(c => char.ToLower(c), c => c)
       ?.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Count() == 1)
       ?.First()
       ?? '\0';
```

**Edit:** if you want to return `string` - "...I need to return an empty string..." -, you can group by `string` while providing required comparer:

```
    private static string FirstNonRepeatedCharacter(string s) => s
       ?.GroupBy(c => c.ToString(), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
       ?.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Count() == 1)
       ?.Key
       ?? "";
```